# ember - combining data for two models into single result for power sort

Tags: ember.js

I'm getting data from two models in one of my routes using RSVP hash, and then trying to combine those results in my controller so that they can be used in a select for power sort. However something doesn't seem to be working.

My route looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            newBook : this.store.createRecord('book'),
            authors : this.store.findAll('author'),
            publishing_houses : this.store.findAll('publishing-house')    
        });
    },

    setupController(controller, model) {
        this._super(...arguments);
        Ember.set(controller, 'authors', model.authors);
        Ember.set(controller, 'publishing_houses', model.publishing_houses);
    },

    actions: {
        save() {
            this.modelFor(this.routeName).get('newBook').save(); 
        }
    }    
});
```

My template looks like this:

```
<form {{action "save" on="submit"}}>
    {{input value=model.newBook.title placeholder="Title"}}<br>
    {{input value=model.newBook.price placeholder="Price"}}<br>

    {{#power-select class="select"
        selected=model.newBook.author
        options=model.authors
        onchange=(action (mut model.newBook.author)) as |author|}}
        {{author.name}}
    {{/power-select}}

    {{#power-select class="select"
        selected=model.newBook.publisher
        options=model.publishers
        onchange=(action (mut model.newBook.publisher)) as |publisher|}}
        {{publisher.name}}
    {{/power-select}}

    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

and my controller, which I think is the problem looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    publishers: function() {
        var authors = this.get("authors");
        var publishingHouses = this.get("publishing_houses");
        return authors.concat(publishingHouses);
    }
});
```

I'm still figuring out how to use controllers. Am I accessing the model data correctly in the controller? Also is this the proper way to create a property to be used in a template?

Answer (score 0):

In `setupController` hook, you don't need to explicitly set `authors` and `publishing_houses` since it will be set by default through super function call.

In your controller, you can try accessing it like `this.get("model.authors")` and in the same way for other properties `publishing_houses`, `newBook`

To access RSVP return model from route, you should access it directly without `get` function.

`this.modelFor(this.routeName).newBook.save()

For concatenation and other stuff you refer http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html

`reduce` might suite your needs.